# why IE dont recognize characters when sending ajax request only with another language like arabic or farsi

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, encoding

I send a string for search with jquery ajax, it is working true in en lang alphanumeric characters, but dont work in cases that typing arabic or farsi lang.

this occur just in IE , this script working in chrome and firefox perfectly!
you can see in here: http://webzzz.com

Comment: not working search module just in IE, just arabic character

Comment: Are you get correct string (correct string encoding) in the server when get `$_GET["query"]`? I think you should work with url decode/encoding functions.

Comment: please visit this screen shot: http://imgs.ir/imgs/201212/Untitled-1.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I solved it: the problem was in the ajax script

```
**// this not working with ie browser when using arabic letters** 
xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

***// this will work in ie browser even with arabic letter after insert uncode(url)***
var uri = "livesearch.php?q="+str ;
var res = encodeURI(uri);
xmlhttp.open("GET",res,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that what is received by the server is correctly encoded. It seems IE7,8,9 has problem with that.

I got a similar problem with AJAX request send with 'GET' method. I solved it by encoding the non-ASCII argument of my request using [`encodeURI(URI)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i get after entering a text in the search box:

[image]

not sure what to expect as it is in arabic.

Comment: no, this search module working with ajax, like facebook search, i mean this future not working in IE (just for arabic lang)

Comment: now, you can search some people and see result without submit form, it is working right now in chrome perferctly